# Dynamic form and alternatives to captcha to avoid form spam

Tags: javascript, forms, spam-prevention

I was wondering, if i'm not wrong the spam robots parse the html source at loading time to detect the presence of a form, am I right?

Would the be of any protection to generate the form dynamically with javascript? (of course you would need js enabled, i wonder who doesn't today)

Another idea i had. I never liked captcha, they stop user flow and if you are wrong you will have to reload the page. I was thinking about an iphone like sliding widget. would it be impossible for robots to get through it, isn't it?

Comment: i believe your `am i wrong?` and `am i right?` don't mean what you think they mean...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the accessibility of any alternative you use to block your spam. Can someone with a visual, mobility or cognitive impairment operate the sliding widget to submit your form? If they cannot, and there is no alternative, such as an audio option, then you are limiting who can submit your form to those without accessibility issues.

Comment: All captcha alternatives I've seen have been orders of magnitude easier to break robotically then captcha. People always come up with these "new ideas" that are easier from a user stand point, but are also easier to robots.

Generally, anything that makes it easier for a human to submit it, will make it easier for a robot. An "iphone slide" would take maybe 15 minutes of coding to automate a solution.

Comment: how could they parse something generated at runtime? this brings back the first question, can robot parse generate source? how could they create a solution for this spam protector if they never saw it. it would be a custom solution and i don't think any spammer would be so interested in my form to code something specifically for this.

Comment: impaired people has any setting on their browser that can be read by js so that in case i can generate a accessibile alterntive?

Comment: @Bakaburg There are no flags that people set. Think of it as having a party and planning things so everyone feels included. Sure, it's extra work, but you'll get good at it and the results are so rewarding. With your project, have you considered using session cookies to hold your form data if the CAPTCHA answer is wrong? There are methods to temporarily hold your form data, so don't give up on the CAPTCHA. Having a good foundation in accessibility is essential as a developer - visit www.unleashwebaccess.com for some gentle tastes and ideas, it's not as dry as the W3C standards readings.

Answer (score 0):

I use javascript to dynamically add a field to all submits, the server ignores any incoming form submissions that don't have it.

It reduces the spam, but isn't a magic bullet. I still get seo spam now and then, on my sight that gets hardly any traffic. They either have 3rd world slaves manually doing form submission, or their form scraping is smart enough to figure out javascript tricks.

Comment: are this hidden fields generated when click is performed on a submit button? maybe the spambot simply trigger the click and so create the fields.

Comment: it's part of my onsubmit handler. After validation finished but before the submit happens. I thought most spambots scrape html and can't run javascript?